# Average all numbers in row for the past 24 hours

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Okay, I am trying to get the average of all the rows with the column 'price' within the last 24 hours.

```
$tickerBuy = $this->model->ticker("date AS datetime, avg(price) as average",$market,"AND buysell='buy' GROUP BY date(24) ","");
```

My date is a datetime, and prices are like 234,356, etc.

I've tried that, but it doesn't work. (and it rightly shoudln't, I just made it for the demo so you know what I am wanting to do.

Comment: That doesn't look like a PDO call to me.

Comment: do you want just one  average number ?

Comment: Yes, just one average number.

Comment: It's because my ticker model has the pdo call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the rows in the past 24 hours, you use:

```
SELECT AVG(price) AS average FROM your_table WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Will this use server time rather than user's local time?